# Padding in dropdown menu in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, padding

I'm trying to play a little bit with CSS of Wordpress. However, I tried so much things but I can't solve it for some reason.

I wanted to have more space between links in the menubar so I added padding. I created to following code:

```
.main-navigation li {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 30px;
```

Here the other CSS code

```
.main-navigation a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;


.main-navigation a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.main-navigation ul ul a:hover,
.main-navigation ul ul a.focus {
    background-color: black;
}


.main-navigation ul ul a {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 200px;
}
```

This worked for me and created more space in the menubar however it's also added the padding to the links in the dropdown menu, which shouldn't be done. I have tried to much things but it seems I cannot solve it. Could someone tell me what I could do? Please see below to see what I mean.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cll0G.png)

Comment: Please post the HTML of your menu bar.

Comment: It's a framework of Wordpress. It's not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
.main-navigation ul ul li {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Solved it thanks! :) I added the padding at li, but adding it at 'a' solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS declaration that you posted, `.main-navigation li {}`, is saying "target every `<li>` that is a descendant of `.main-navigation`". So your `<li>` elements that are in the next level of lists also get targeted.

You can use the `>` child selector to select only direct children of the parent. So the following code should work for you, and not affect the dropdown elements:

```
.main-navigation > li {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 30px;
}
```